# Remove Bill To Address from Order in Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to modify the form in Dynamics CRM Online (2013) for our orders. I want to remove the Bill To Address, but each time I try to remove it from from the form, it keeps saying the field is required by the business or the system.

How do I stop making this field required so that I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the field and turn off 'Visible by default' to hide it.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWiz.png)

If you have a lot of fields to hide, you can move them all into a new section and turn off 'Visible by default' for the section rather then individual fields.